# CSS translate percentage meaning

Tags: css, transform, translate

When there is css style like below:

```
.text-box {
    width: 90%;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Where is translate's percentage based on? The body? or the parent div? -50% of what?

Answer (score 3):

Actually this percentage based on size of "reference box" which defined by `transform-box` property. You can see details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box).

To put it simple, by default this based on size (width/height) of element which class applied to.

Answer (score 2):

According to the spec and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate#values), it's based on the `transform-box` property.

The spec for [transform-box](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box) outlines the values and what that means. The default in the browser is still  `content-box` which is defined as,

> content-box
> Uses the content box as reference box. The reference box of a table is the border box of its table wrapper box, not its table box.

So lots of words to say it's based on the size of the element assigned the class.

Comment: On the size, not on the position.